# Why is absorption spectrum of beta-carotene different from Zeaxanthin?

Tags: spectroscopy, photochemistry, uv-vis-spectroscopy

Here are the molecular structures of beta-carotene and zeaxanthin

[image: beta-carotene][image: zeaxanthin]

These molecules only differ in the OH groups and the conjugated backbone length is exactly the same. I read that the absorption spectrum of a molecule is decided by the conjugation length. How is it then, that the absorption spectrum of the two molecules are different as shown below:

[image]

Comment: These spectra have vibronic structure, the differences might be related to different vibrations. Consider that the lineshape is an effect of unresolved vibronic transitions, local environment, and solvent effects (OH groups have a role in this), thus the small differences could be explained like this.

Comment: Do they all in same solvent or different solvents?

Comment: The spectra are very similar in energy terms. The bands/peaks are due to vibrational transitions in the first  excited state  (as mentioned by Anon). The OH groups change the electronic energy level of the conjugated bonds very slightly, in energy terms $\approx 420$ wavenumbers in $\approx 20800$ wavenumbers. A v. small perturbation to the energy consistent with the position of the OH.

Comment: One more note: solvents effect can be merely dielectric, ie for rigid molecules, or modify substantially the energy levels via conformational effect on the solute. This is particularly true in extended conjugated system. A linear chain that coils have a reduced effective conjugation length. I want to point out that one can have very drastic solvatochromic effects and they also can be modulated by more or less little differences.

Comment: @all, thank you for giving me the keywords to do further study on this